# iPhone UIButton action is not working

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I create UIView and then I add UIButton as subview with action, but this action is never called.

Does anybody know why?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    UIView *roundResultView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 150)];
    UIImageView *_popUpBg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NotificationBg.png"]];
    _popUpBg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, roundViewWidth, roundViewHeight);

    UIButton *closeButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 30)];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeAndBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [closeButton setTitle:@"Back") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [roundResultView addSubview:_popUpBg];
    [roundResultView addSubview:closeButton];
    [self.view addSubview:roundResultView];
}


-(void)closeAndBack{
    NSLog(@"closeAndBack"); //never called
}
```

I have checked this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [closeButton allControlEvents]);
NSLog(@"%@", [closeButton allTargets]);
```

and it prints:

```
... Sedmica[2192:14f03] 64
... Sedmica[2192:14f03] {(
    <ViewController: 0x8631e10>
)}
```

Comment: did you tried with breakpoints in viewDidLoad and closeAndBack?

Comment: No. I don't know to work with breakpoints. Can you give me advice how to do that?

Comment: on left hand side just on the outer side/wall click, a blue breakpoint will be created. and then you can step over. on bottom side there will be many buttons to step over, step into etc...

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with this and kindly let me know :

```
UIButton *closeButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[closeButton addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(closeAndBack:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[closeButton setTitle:@"Back"
             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, 100.0, 30.0);
[self.view addSubview:closeButton];
```

---

```
- (IBAction)closeAndBack:(UIButton *)button{
      NSLog(@"Button  clicked.");
}
```

Comment: no click efect like with my code. Like something is over that button and I can't click on it.

Comment: remove _popUpBg subview and try

Comment: No efect. I even try with: [self.view bringSubviewToFront:roundResultView];

Comment: Sorry, your code is working but that is not the solution because I'm creating custom UIView which I am adding to self.view like a subview. Please take a look at my code again.

Comment: you should first add `[self.view addSubview:roundResultView];` then add `closeButton`, But i am not sure...if there ordering make any difference.

Comment: Solved. My another UILabel was over the UIButton but is has not backgroundColor so I could not see this problem. Should I write this to an answer or? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes you can write your answer yourself :)